# MariaDB SQL Query inner join table messages with table users

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to have a select query that is something similar to :

```
SELECT messages.id,users.username as name_from,users.username as name_to,messages.content
 FROM messages
 INNER JOIN users
 ON messages.id_from=name_from AND messages.id_to=name_to
```

(just for reference)
but this gets me a syntax error since I cant use name_from and name_to in the ON clause

I have users:

|-id-|-username-|-password-|
|--1-|......user1...|..................|
|--2-|......user2...|..................|

and messages:

|-id-|--id_from--|--id_to--|--content--|
|--1-|......1........|.....2......|.................|
|--2-|......2........|.....1......|.................|

the result of the query should be :

|-id-|--name_from--|--name_to--|--content--|
|--1-|......user1.......|......user2.....|................|
|--2-|......user2.......|......user1.....|................|

Any of you can please give me the query for the result and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want two joins for two names:

```
SELECT m.id, uf.username as name_from, u.tusername as name_to, m.content
FROM messages m JOIN
     users uf
     ON m.id_from = uf.id JOIN
     users ut
     ON m.id_to = ut.id;
```

You have some holes in your thinking about this problem.  The biggest is that the connection between `messages` and `users` is based on `users.id` -- and that is nowhere in your query.

The rest is structuring the query so it returns both names, but after the joins on the respective ids.

Also note that column aliases defined in the `SELECT` cannot be used elsewhere in the `SELECT`, `FROM`, or `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: Yes that's what I actually wanted! thanks a lot man 
Just a little typo at the beginning , ut.username instead of u.username

Answer (score 0):

You should join the users table twice.

And I would go for `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN` as it is more appropriate.

```sql
SELECT 
    messages.id,
    u1.username as name_from,
    u2.username as name_to,
    messages.content
FROM messages
    LEFT JOIN users u1 
        ON messages.id_from = u1.id
    LEFT JOIN users u2
        ON messages.id_to = u2.id
```

The key here is that you join the tables with forign keys from messages table and their corresponding primary key from users table